# Difference between "find" and "search"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

What is the difference between *find* and *search*? Please suggest the proper usage.

Comment: Same difference as in Russian, actually (and French and German and Spanish...). *Найти* vs *искать*.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*To search for something* means "to try to find something."
Vice versa, to find something doesn't mean to have searched. *Find* generally means *discover*, *reach*, *arrive at*, or *perceive*.

> She also found the time to raise five children.
>   Vitamin B12 is found in dairy products.
>   Water finds its own level.

In these sentences, *find* doesn't imply a search has been done.

Answer (score 13):

You search for something you need to find.

> I searched on the internet. I found
>   what I was looking for.

Comment: To add - you can also *find* something without searching, if you just came across it like a book or a shop in a street.

Comment: Of course. Good point.

Comment: You can also search for something without finding it.

Answer (score 9):

*Find* is more about the discovery, the end result.

*Search* says nothing about the end result.

Answer (score 3):

Find implies that it has a fixed position and can be located using coordinates.  Like you'd find the hotel on the map, you wouldn't search for it.  Search brings to mind a rummaging through some filer or sorting through objects until you stumble across the item you're looking for.  Alternatively search could be used to imply a sort of easter egg hunt where there may be more than one item you're looking for.

Examples of find:

```
I found the hotel on the map.
Find the area of the triangle.
I found a great spot to hang out.
```

Examples of search:

```
Could you search for the car keys?
Search for a nice indian restaurant on google.
Search for a file on C:\.
```

However, they're similar enough that even if you used search rather than find or vice versa, it would make little difference.